# Where is my.ini in MacOS Sierra

Tags: mysql, macos

I installed mysql with homebrew with this guide https://gist.github.com/nrollr/3f57fc15ded7dddddcc4e82fe137b58e

Now I need to delete the server variable NO_ZERO_DATE from the mysql configuration but i don't found mysql conf file. Where is located this file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In MacOS the my.ini file is found as my.cnf, you can look for it in terminal with

```
> mysql --help
```

"Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/local/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf"

But if you hadn't found the cnf in the locations that help show you, try with the next command

```
> ls $(brew --prefix mysql)/support-files/my-*
```

For example, I got this file

```
/usr/local/opt/mysql/support-files/my-default.cnf
```

then you need to copy this file to one of your default directories, in my case **/etc/my.cnf**

```
> sudo cp /usr/local/opt/mysql/support-files/my-default.cnf /etc/my.cnf
```

Finally open your cnf file and delete **STRICT_TRANS_TABLES** from **sql_mode**

```
> nano /etc/my.cnf

sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

Exit with **ctrl+x** and press **S**

Don't forget to restart your mysql server

```
> sudo mysql.server stop
> sudo mysql.server start
```